# Making a div with a transparent background image behind non-transparent list

Tags: html, css, angularjs

How do I make a div that has a background image behind a list, so that the list itself doesn't become transparent?

I'm trying it like this right now:

```
<div class="talking-points" style="background: url({{talkingPointsImage}}); background-size: 100%; opacity: 0.05; 0 0">
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="issue in subCategories" style="list-style-type:none; opacity: 1;">
            <input type="radio" name="radio" ng-model="question.stance" ng-value="-1"> {{issue.issue}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Right now, its making the entire thing transparent. One problem is that I'm using Angular $scope to place the image path into this skeleton page, so it seems like this has to be declared in the .html so that Angular picks it up.

Answer (score 0):

I normally do it using `before` or `after`

```
li {
    background: transparent;
    position: relative
}

li:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url('YourBGImage.jpg');
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0
}
```

Comment: the problem with that, is that I have to designate the background-image in the HTML so that angular can inject the image path.. I figured it out, though so I'll post that in a sec

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out to just do it with another div. The secret to that is not putting the  tag below the list. Just put  above the list. Otherwise, it will cancel your list out - confused me.

Another problem that's now obvious is the color of the transparent background is slightly different from whats around it. Looks like I'll have to use some .PNGs instead!

```css
.backgroundImage {
 position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: .4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

<div class="talking-points">
 <div class="backgroundImage" style="background: url({{talkingPointsImage}}) center center;"></div>

 <h2>{{title}}</h2>
 <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="issue in subCategories" style="list-style-type:none; opacity: 1;">
         <input type="radio" name="radio" ng-model="question.stance" ng-value="-1"> {{issue.issue}}
     </li>
 </ul>
 

</div>
</div>
```